# How to read a text file into an array, count the number of occurrences and then display the count

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The text file is contains random symbols and I want to count the digits 0 - 9.

I'm struggling to figure out how to read the text file into an array, how to correctly count occurrences of the specific digits into an array and then display the number of occurrences using methods.

Here is my code so far:

```
  // Get the filename.
  System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
  String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

  // Open the file.
  File file = new File(filename);
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  char [] charMap = new char [1380];

  // Read lines from the file until no more are left.
  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     // Read the map.
     String map = inputFile.nextLine();
     charMap = map.toCharArray();

     // Display the map.
     System.out.println(charMap);
  }

  // Close the file.
  inputFile.close();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example this is the working example if you want to count the digits in each line in file.

```
// Read lines from the file until no more are left.
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            // Read the map.
            String map = inputFile.nextLine();
            charMap = map.toCharArray();

            // Display the map.
            System.out.println(countNumber(charMap));
        }
```

//method

```
private static int countNumber(char[] chars) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Alternatively if you can do it in simplest way, 1) Read the whole file content as a string, 2) Build the array from the string, 3) Count from them as example below:

```
String inputFile = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\z").next();

char[] charMap = inputFile.toCharArray();
System.out.println(countNumber(charMap));
```